# How to inherit from a SwiftUI Button

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to inherit from a Button in SwiftUI? I tired it and I get an error every time, since `Button` is expecting some kind of generic argument.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonSubClass: Button<Label: View> {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

XCode automatically adds the `<Label: View>` part, but I don't know what it means or what I actually need to put in the braces.
I tried `Button<View>`, but then I get the error `Protocol type 'View' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols`

Comment: What are you intend to do?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67972148/14351818

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Button` is a struct, which cannot be subclassed. If you are trying to create a custom `View` with `Button`-like properties, but customized in some way, you can apply view modifiers or use the `ButtonStyle` protocol.

If you can supply some specifics of what you are trying to accomplish, I will try to add some example code.

Comment: What if we are asked by some crazy UI designers to add some Android style animation to a Button?